# Ubuntu 14.10 can't install libplrpc-perl, and php-bcmath

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, 14.10, php

My system is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 14.10

Release:        14.10

Codename:       utopic
```

when I try to

> apt-get install libplrpc-perl

, and `php-bcmath` it tells me that

> "E: Unable to locate package"

How do I install these two packages for my self made Apache2,PHP,MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

`bcmath`  is builtin as an included module in the packages `php5-fpm`  and 
`libapache2-mod-php5`

And since that the `php5-fpm` system as well as the `libapache2-mod-php5` plugin is  included by default in apache installtion,then you don't  have to install any additional packages or plugins to get bcmath.

Now for libplrpc-perl update your source list then try to install:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libplrpc-perl
```